# Changing collection, CollectionChanged always null

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm going around in circles trying to figure this out.

I'm swapping out one set of data in a collection for another set of data. My UI which displays the data shows the first set fine on load of the control, but does not change to the new set of data when I change the collection content.

I'm expecting that CollectionChanged in the NotifyCollectionChanged method to have a subscription, but it does not.

StationName shows on my UI on load, but does not change on reload. 
The StationListOfMovements shows on my UI on load, but does not change on reload.

I can change individual items in the existing collection in code. Where am I going wrong here?

**The control which displays the data**

```
public partial class CisArrivalsPanel : UserControl
    {
        private ApiDataArrivalsDepartures _theArrivalsDepartures;

        public CisArrivalsPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _theArrivalsDepartures = new ApiDataArrivalsDepartures();

            _theArrivalsDepartures = MakeQuery.LiveTrainArrivals("London Kings Cross"); //load the first set of data into the collection

            this.DataContext = _theArrivalsDepartures;

            ListBoxArr.ItemsSource = _theArrivalsDepartures.StationMovementList;            
        }


        //this invokes the data collection reload as a test
        private void StationHeader_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Reload();

            Debug.WriteLine(_theArrivalsDepartures.StationName);
            foreach (var a in _theArrivalsDepartures.StationMovementList)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(a.OriginName);
                Debug.WriteLine(a.BestArrivalEstimateMins);
            }
        }

        //here I am swapping out the collection contents
        void Reload()
        {
            _theArrivalsDepartures = MakeQuery.LiveTrainArrivals("London Paddington"); //load the second set of data into the collection

        }
    }
```

**The collection**

```
public class ApiDataArrivalsDepartures : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _stationName;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "station_name")]
        public string StationName {
            get
            {
                return _stationName;
            }
            set
            {
                _stationName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("StationName");
            } 
        }

        private DateTime _requestTime;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "request_time")]
        public DateTime RequestTime {
            get
            {
                return _requestTime;
            }
            set
            {
                _requestTime = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("RequestTime");
            } 
        }

        private string _stationCode;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "station_code")]
        public string StationCode {
            get
            {
                return _stationCode;
            }
            set
            {
                _stationCode = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("StationCode");
            } 
        }

        private ObservableCollection<StationListOfMovements> _stationMovementList;

        public ObservableCollection<StationListOfMovements> StationMovementList
        {
            get
            {
                return _stationMovementList;
            }
            set
            {
                _stationMovementList = value;
                NotifyCollectionChanged("StationMovementList");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }

        public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        private void NotifyCollectionChanged(string property)
        {
            if (CollectionChanged != null)
            {
                CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset,property));    
            }            
        }
    }


    public class StationListOfMovements : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _mode;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mode")]
        public string Mode
        {
            get
            {
                return _mode;
            }
            set
            {
                _mode = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Mode");
            }
        }


        private string _service;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "service")]
        public string Service {
            get
            {
                return _service;
            }
            set
            {
                _service = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Service");
            } 
        }

        private string _trainUid;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "train_uid")]
        public string TrainUid {
            get
            {
                return _trainUid;
            }
            set
            {
                _trainUid = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TrainUid");
            } 
        }

        private string _originName;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "origin_name")]
        public string OriginName {
            get
            {
                return _originName;
            }
            set
            {
                _originName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("OriginName");
            } 
        }

        private string _destinationName;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "destination_name")]
        public string DestinationName {
            get
            {
                return _destinationName;
            }
            set
            {
                _destinationName = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DestinationName");
            } 
        }

        private string _platform;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Platform")]
        public string Platform {
            get
            {
                return _platform;
            }
            set
            {
                _platform = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Platform");
            }
        }

   //This is a long boring class, snipped until....

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update1:**

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Gets train arrivals for a station
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="station">The station.</param>
        /// <returns>ApiDataArrivalsDepartures</returns>
        public static ApiDataArrivalsDepartures LiveTrainArrivals(string station)
        {

            string crsCode;
            OvergroundStations.StationDictionary.TryGetValue(station, out crsCode);

            //construct url
            var queryUrl = new Uri(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",ApiBaseUrl,"train/station/",crsCode,"/live_arrivals"));

            //get json data from API 
            var jsonString = GetDataFromApi(queryUrl);

            //convert to root arrival object
            var arrivals = Deseralise<ApiDataArrivalsDepartures>(jsonString) as ApiDataArrivalsDepartures;

            //convert arrivals board data
            if (arrivals != null)
                arrivals.StationMovementList = Deseralise<ObservableCollection<StationListOfMovements>>(jsonString, "arrivals", "all") as ObservableCollection<StationListOfMovements>;

            return arrivals;
        }
```

**Update 2:**

```
static object Deseralise<T>(string jsonString, string token1, string token2)
        {
            var deserializeObject = new object();

            try
            {
                var jsonPass1 = JObject.Parse(jsonString).SelectToken(token1).ToString();

                var jsonPass2 = JObject.Parse(jsonPass1).SelectToken(token2).ToString();

                deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonPass2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }

            return deserializeObject;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` will raise `CollectionChanged` *automatically*, there is **no need** to raise it yourself. It is also raising it against itself, not your VM.

In fact, the UI has no reason to register for it (hence the null event handler), since your VM doesn't even implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` (not that you should be).

Instead, call `NotifyPropertyChanged` in the `set` function for your collection, and get rid of `CollectionChanged`. Also make sure that *every* time you set the variable, you do so through the **Property** and not the backing **field**. Setting through the field will not run the `set` function of the property, so `NotifyPropertyChanged` won't run.

**Update**
While my original observations are still good things to be aware of, I now notice the actual problem:

```
    //here I am swapping out the collection contents
    void Reload()
    {
        _theArrivalsDepartures = MakeQuery.LiveTrainArrivals("London Paddington"); //load the second set of data into the collection
    }
```

The `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` is *still* set to the old collection! All you have done is reassign your local variable, the `ListBox` is not affected at all. Gotchas like this are why you typically *don't* set UI properties directly. Instead, you would **bind** `ItemsSource` to a property on your VM, and then *only change that property* instead of swapping out the whole object.

In the mean time, consider just reassigning `ItemsSource` to the new collection.

Comment: I'm starting to get the feeling you're following me ;) having made the change (NotifyPropertyChanged("StationMovementList");) my UI still does not change when the collection does

Comment: @Damo Lol, following you: no. Following [tag:C#] and [tag:WPF], yes :) Are you making to sure to set the *Property* and not the *Field* (several pieces of your code set the field). The setter, and thus the event, won't fire unless you are modifying the property

Comment: The collection code above is pretty much it. (I just snipped some of the properties and fields out) I'm not setting fields anywhere else other than as part of the property.

Comment: @Damo Can you show the assignment to `StationMovementList`? I believe you, but if you are raising `NotifyPropertyChanged` then thats the next most common mistake.

Comment: I'm more than willing to accept a daft error here. Updated to show the backing class MakeQuery.LiveTrainArrivals

Comment: @Damo Thanks! It appears to have been a daft error I could have spotted in your original code :) Sorry for the confusion, see my update.

Comment: I need to take a step back onto some basics of binding to controls I think.  (UI's are not my thing).

Comment: @Damo I'm always around in the WPF chat room if you want to chat :). If I happen to *not* be around, just ping me to make sure I get the message. Feel free to link to any questions you want me to look at here as well. Hers a link to the room in case you haven't used chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf